# Парсинг XML с помощью XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, парсер

Нужно парсить такой файл, но у меня все косо выходит... Можете объяснить?

[image: Код]

Сейчас написал такой код:

```java
private static final String LANGUAGE_TAG = "language";
    private static final String FILE_TAG = "file";

    public static ArrayList<Language> loadLanguage() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>();
        Language lang = new Language();

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(loadFile("data/languages.xml")));

        while(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                switch (parser.getName())
                {
                    case LANGUAGE_TAG: {
                        lang.id = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                        lang.name = parser.getAttributeValue(1);
                        break;
                    }
                    case FILE_TAG: {
                        lang.paths.add(parser.getAttributeValue(1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName() == LANGUAGE_TAG){
                languages.add(lang);
                lang.paths.clear();
            }
            parser.next();
        }

        return languages;
    }
```

Будет такое работать?

Вот сам XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<languages>
    <language id="ru" name="Русский">
        <file id="description" path="Languages/ru/description.xml"/>
        <file id="titles" path="Languages/ru/titles.xml"/>
        <file id="interface" path="Languages/ru/interface.xml"/>
    </language>
    <language id="en" name="English">
        <file id="description" path="Languages/en/description.xml"/>
        <file id="titles" path="Languages/en/titles.xml"/>
        <file id="interface" path="Languages/en/interface.xml"/>
    </language>
    <language id="uk" name="Український">
        <file id="description" path="Languages/uk/description.xml"/>
        <file id="titles" path="Languages/uk/titles.xml"/>
        <file id="interface" path="Languages/uk/interface.xml"/>
    </language>
</languages>
```

Comment: Показывай как пробовал.

Comment: @Tolikol вставтье xml как тект, а не картинкой. и покажите как именно вы пытались распарсить его.

Comment: Уже вставил текст.

Comment: Что косо выглядит? Распарсинные данные? Напишите конкретно что нужно распарсить, объяснить, или и то и другое.

Comment: Косо было то, что данные были только с первого тега "language". Он дальше читать не хотел. Сейчас написал тот код, что вверху и сейчас проверю его.

Comment: Оно парсит, но в списке все элементы это последний тэг в XML. Короче, оно список только украинским заполняет, а стальных нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что одна и та же структура Lang переиспользуется для каждого последующего раздела, поэтому значения в ней затираются, соответственно сохраняются лишь значения для последнего раздела.

Для правильной обработки нужно при начале каждого элемента LANG создавать новый объект, примерно так:

```
if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
{
    switch (parser.getName())
    {
        case LANGUAGE_TAG: {
            lang = new Lang();
            lang.id = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
            lang.name = parser.getAttributeValue(1);
            break;
        }
        case FILE_TAG: {
            lang.paths.add(parser.getAttributeValue(1));
            break;
        }
    }
} else if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName() == LANGUAGE_TAG){
    languages.add(lang);
}
parser.next();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Думал так сделать, но решил отложить на завтра, а потом увидел ваш ответ и попробовал - все работает.